# Windows batch file command formatting with usebackq

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to assign the results of a git command to a variable in a Windows batch file.

The line in question looks like:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%i IN (`git rev-parse --short=12 trunk`) DO set IMAGE_NAME=buildroot-buildenv-%%i
```

When I run this I get `fatal: Needed a single revision`, I assume because there is a command formatting issue with the `--short=12` part of the command. (If I simply run `git rev-parse trunk` as the command, everything works fine)

How can I add the `--short=12` option to the git command and get the proper result?

Comment: You need to escape the `=` in the `git` command with a caret (`^=12` not `=12`)

Comment: As well as the advice received in the comment, and subsequent answer, there is absolutely no need to **use back q**uotes. You should, for absolute safety use ```@Set "IMAGE_NAME=" & For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('^""%LocalAppData%\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe" rev-parse --short^=12 trunk 2^>NUL^"') Do @Set "IMAGE_NAME=buildroot-buildenv-%%G"```. Then you could follow up with ```@If Not Defined IMAGE_NAME Exit /B```, and only proceed beyond that with `%IMAGE_NAME%` as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment by Magoo

> You need to escape the `=` in the git command with a caret (`^=12` not `=12`)

Solved it for me